# how to iterate a list created by linq

Tags: c#, linq

How can I iterate a list that I got from database with linq? Here is my code below. 
In the `for` loop, condition `i < elements.Count` gives error:

> "Operand '<' cannot be applied to operands of type int and method group".

how can I fix this?

```
var elements = from element in db_.EMAILFAXNOTIFICATION
                       where element.TARIH == dt_
                       && element.CLCARDID == cl_id
                       select element;

for (int i = 0; i < elements.Count; i++)
{

}
```

Comment: use `foreach(var e in elements)` to avoid iterating on your query twice

Comment: also have you thought about refactoring the results of the select to return `select element.ToList()` from there you could do a `foreach(string s in elements){}` for example since foreach works very well against a Collection if you want to get even deeper ..the List<T> will allow you to do List<T>.foreach create a delegate of string if so needed..

Comment: down voters, why downvote?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're getting the error because you forgot to invoke the `Count` method:

```
for (int i = 0; i < elements.Count(); i++)
{

}
```

Note that calling `Count()` processes the entire sequence though--then you'll be iterating over the sequence *again* to access each element. As [@Scott](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26961633/how-to-iterate-a-list-created-by-linq-in-c-sharp#comment42461630_26961651) points out below, since the loop condition is evaluated on each iteration of the loop, `Count` is called N+1 times, where N is the size of your sequence.

To avoid this, use a [`foreach`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6.aspx) loop instead.

```
foreach (var element in elements)
{
    // Do something with element
}
```

Comment: Note: the for int loop will iterate the list TWICE. Once to figure out Count(), then again to iterate it.  Always use foreach unless you need access the index itself.  Even then, consider incrementing an integer in the foreach, to save yourself a wasted set of iterations.

Comment: @SteveLillis it is worse than that, it will iterate `Count()` times + 1 because it will perform the comparison once per loop and the value does not get cached.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain You would presumably also have to use `ElementAt` in the for loop which makes it even worse than that.

Comment: +1. Also note that you can often get good help on error messages by clicking F1 in Visual Studio when error is selected. Unfortunately in this case error caused by 2 problems [CS0019](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a63h61ky.aspx) and something like [CS0428](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/02dw211c(v=vs.90).aspx) which makes it harder to diagnose.